# Rails: form_for setting Nested Routes with custom action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, routes

I have a problem with nested routes with custom action. I want to make a form url path: `localhost:3000/requests/2/images/create_for_request`. Where the custom action: `create_for_request` is called in the `ImagesController`, with the `request_id` from `requests/show.html.erb`. 
Below is the error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"create_for_request", :controller=>"requests", :id=>"11"}
```

request.rb:

```
class Request < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  alias_attribute :requester, :user
  has_many :requests_has_images
  has_many :response_images, through: :requests_has_images, class_name: 'Image', source: 'image'
  has_many :chosen_images, lambda {where(chosen: true)}, through: :requests_has_images, class_name: 'Image', source: 'image'

  def is_requester(user)
    if user && self.user_id == user.id
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end  
end
```

config.rb

```
  resources :requests do
    post 'images/create_for_request' => 'images#create_for_request'
    put 'images/edit_for_request' => 'images#edit_for_request'
    post 'images/delete_for_request' => 'images#delete_for_request'
  end
```

requests/show.html.erb:

```
<h2>Make Response Image</h2>
# Send this form for image to image controller with request_id of this request
<%= form_for [@request, @request.response_images.build], url: url_for(action: 'create_for_request') do |f|  %>
<p>
```

images_controller.rb:

```
  def create_for_request    
    @request = Request.find(params[:request_id])    
    if @request          
      @image = Image.new(image_params)
      add_file_params(@image)
      @image.request = @request
      if @image.save       
        redirect_to request_path(@request)
      end     
    else
     #TODO show error no such request 
    end
  end
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned `@request.images.build` in form but I don't see that you have any association like Request `has_many :images` instead you have several other association which involves image. I dont what which association you exactly want to build there so I can only suggest that change that `build` to actual association you want and also you may need to adjust your `create_for_request` a little based on that.

EDIT:
OP changed `@request.images.build` line in posted question to fix the issue. and solution to his new problem mentioned in comment section of this answer is to change the `controller` in form declaration. since you are referring `a action` which is not present in `Request` controller.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want to create resource_image for the request. But when I put @request.resource_image.build. It prints out error that there is no such method in the Request model

Comment: Again you dont have that association, you have only `requests_has_images`, `response_images`, `chosen_images`

Comment: Oh right, that fixed one problem. I will edit my question. The problem now is this error: 'No route matches {:action=>"create_for_request", :controller=>"requests", :id=>"11"}`

Comment: Thats because `create_for_request` is in `ImagesController` not in `RequestsController` so change that in form accordingly

Comment: Can you help me solve this nested routing problem? If I explicitly specifies: 'controller: "image" ' it said no routes match 'create_for_request' for image controller. This is because it is a nested route.

Comment: I think it should be `images` . Try this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126090/discussion-between-long-le-and-sajan).